# Why i am not getting output in teminal Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

```
function helloworldapp() {
  console.log("Hello World");
}
```

I am new to Ndoejs. I have installed node on my windows 10 and in cmd i type node-v it showing me the installed version of nodejs , but when i craeted project on vscode and type node app.js (js file name). it does not showing me any thing in teminal. how can i get output of my nodejs program in terminal?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is everything you put in the `app.js` file, you are not calling your function.

```
function helloworldapp() {
  console.log("Hello world");
}

helloworldapp()
```

I suggest you follow the nodejs getting started guide. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/

Answer (score 3):

You are only defining the function `helloworldapp`, not calling it.

do `helloworldapp()` to execute the function